# There's a way to analyse an cad model file (.stl per example) to get his measures?

Tags: autocad, measure, autodesk, cad

I want to analyse an 3D model of my car and check if his measures are right, i want to do that automatically, just importing the file and the program analyzing him.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [load the geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)), parse all the 3D points, and get min/max extents in XYZ directions.

Here is the pseudocode:

```
     Point3D min = new Point3D(double.MaxValue, double.MaxValue, double.MaxValue)
     Point3D max = new Point3D(double.MinValue, double.MinValue, double.MinValue)

     for (int i = 0; i < verts.Len; i++)
     {

         Point3D p = verts[i];

         if (p.X < min.X)

             min.X = p.X;

         if (p.X > max.X)

             max.X = p.X;

         if (p.Y < min.Y)

             min.Y = p.Y;

         if (p.Y > max.Y)

             max.Y = p.Y;

         if (p.Z < min.Z)

             min.Z = p.Z;

         if (p.Z > max.Z)

             max.Z = p.Z;
     }
```

Comment: I have a lot of rules to be verified, for each rule that i have i need do make an if?
And how i can import and STL file on mobile?